# dotnet core install fails

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, dotnet

i'm trying to install the microsoft .netcore using these instructions (https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu) on ubuntu 17.04.  When I try to install dotnet-dev-1.0.4 it says

myadmin@hadoopnode0:~$ sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-dev-1.0.4 : Depends: dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.1.2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
myadmin@hadoopnode0:~$
I found a web page that talks about similar problems (https://shazwazza.com/post/installing-net-core-101-on-ubuntu-1610/) but after following all the steps successfully it still says there is a problem.

any ideas?  This is frustrating...

Answer (score 1):

At the time being, `Ubuntu 17.04` is **not yet supported** with .NET Core... :-(

The supported versions of Ubuntu are
(according to [Get Started with .NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu) as of 2017-05-17):

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Ubuntu 16.10

Also, Linux Mint *17* is supported, which raised my hopes until I noticed the missing `zesty` feed from `https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/`.

Comment: thanks Flo.  The crazy part is though that it actually installs fine on the GUI version of ubuntu 17.04.  But not the server version.  :/  Wish I knew what the difference was.

Comment: I could not find from which Repository to install package `dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.1.2` from. Could you find that package somewhere in the GUI version?